# recursively count files in folder and output to file

Tags: powershell

I want to count files for every folder on an E-drive, and output the folder path and file count to a text file using PowerShell (version 2).

I have found this script, but it outputs to console. How do I change it to output to a text file?

```
Set-Location -Path E:\
Get-ChildItem -recurse |  Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object{ Write-Host $_.FullName (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to get an array of resulting **objects** where you can store both the directory path and the number of files it contains. That way, you can afterwards show it in the console and also save it to a structured CSV file you can open in Excel.

This is for PowerShell 2:

```
# to keep the property order in PS version < 3.0, create an 
# Ordered Dictionary to store the properties first
$dict = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary

# now loop over the folders
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\' -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
          Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | 
          ForEach-Object {
            # add the results in the temporary ordered dictionary
            $dict.Add('Directory', $_.FullName)
            $dict.Add('Files', @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                                 Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }).Count)
            # and output a PSObject to be collected in array '$result'
            New-Object PSObject -Property $dict
            $dict.Clear()
        }

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

#output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\FileCount.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>The `-Force` switch makes sure you also count items that otherwise can't be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
Get-ChildItem c:\tmp -recurse |
    Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer } |
        ForEach-Object {
            "$($_.Fullname) $((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer}).count)" 
        } |
            Out-File c:\tmp\out.txt
```

Comment: The -Directory parameter is not supported by PowerShell 2.

Comment: Same issue, the -Directory parameter is still in your script.

Comment: Please note that you can always [edit] your answer. There is no need to update large pieces of your answer in a comment.

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: I edited the script, I hope everything is correct now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `>` operator for this:

```
Set-Location -Path E:\
(Get-ChildItem -recurse |  Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object{ Write-Host $_.FullName (Get-ChildItem $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }) >"OUTPUTFILEPATH.txt"
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. The file was created but empty. I guess the Write-Host command has to be routed to the text file, and append its output to the file. So I prefer output to console as well as to the text file.